# Connecting a NodeJS container to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

Before marking this post as a duplicate note that I've already looked at the other related posts here and pretty much everywhere I could without finding a solution to my precise case. I just keep getting confused between `docker-compose.yml` versions and linking the ports to each other.

***Here's the issue:***
I've created two containers with Docker, one hosting a NodeJS server, one hosting a MySQL database.

My **docker-compose.yml** looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:

  server:
    build: ./server/
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dashboard_nodejs
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  client:
    image: angular_app
    build: ./front/
    ports:
      - "4242:80"
    depends_on:
      - server
```

When running `docker-compose up`, all of my apps are built and run without an issue until the server tries to connect to MySQL, exiting with :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:3306 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
```

The **dockerfile** for my database only contains

```
FROM mysql

COPY init_db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

and **init_db.sql** currently is

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dashboard_nodejs;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dashboard_nodejs.*
TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Finally, my server attemps to establish the connection with the following parameters:

```
var con = mySql.createConnection({
    host: "db",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "dashboard_nodejs"
});
```

I have no clue why the connection is refused by mysql even with (what looks to me like) the right credentials.
I apologize in advance if this particular case has already been discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ports: "3306:3306"` to the db service.

Comment: I've tested that, this is the result:

`ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint <db>: Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306: unexpected error Permission denied`

Comment: What OS do you use? Can you try to run it `priviledged: true` Don't do it permanently, just try out, because it is a security risk.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Pro. Where am I supposed to add that attribute `privileged` attribute ?

Comment: To the db service right after the build line. Also are You sure, that no previous container uses the 3306 port? check it with `docker ps -a`